# How to implement this tree view in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, binary-tree

I need to implement a binary tree view attached in the diagram. The process is going like this. First, start in position#1. Then need to print P#2.After p#3.As binary tree method need print left first then right. This is for pyramid system. Please check the example below how this should be. Each node represents the customer(By ID) and his position.

Ex: Let's assume out customerID is number 01 and he might have 5 positions in the tree representing his ID #1, Like in the diagram. And customer number2 have 3 positions in a tree. So we have a lot of customers and some have more than 20 positions in each node.
I need a solution to implement this view. Please note this is not relevant for binary search tree. Thank you!

[Please check the image in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsDmZ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to implement a breadth first search but with an unusual order for returning the results whereby you take one item from each child in a row and interleave them.

So you will need to proceed row-by-row: build a list of nodes at that level, and then to get the next level take all of the left children of each and then all of the right children of each of each to form the next level. This will disentangle your curious tree and you will visit the nodes in this order:

```
  Position #1
  LEFTS = { P#1 }, RIGHTS = { P#2 }
  LEFTS = { P#3 P#4}, RIGHTS = { P#5 P#6 }
  LEFTS = { P#7 P#8 P#9 P#10 }, RIGHTS = { P#11 P#12 P#13 P#14 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try to follow your order